# Film accidentally rewind

Tags: nikon, 35mm, slr, error, kodak

My film roll has rewound. I have taken about 28 out of 36 films before i put the camera down for awhile. When i picked it up to use again, my film count has rewound back to 0 and noticed that i have been taking photos all over again. Will my 28 films most likely be developed or have i lost it all?
I have not tried opening up the film case under dark conditions.
The model of the camera is a SLR Nikon F60.
Would appreciate any advise, thank you.

Comment: What number does the counter show now?

Comment: you have double-exposed all images you have shot over. You can shoot in a dark room with the lens cap on until you get to frame 29, then shoot your last 7 shots normally.

Comment: @dandavis Please post your answer as an answer, not as a comment. It would also be useful if you explained why you think all the frames have been double-exposed and why, when the film was rewound, it didn't come off the take-up spool and all go back into the film cassette.

Comment: Actually, according to the [manual](https://www.cameramanuals.org/nikon_pdf/nikon_n60.pdf), if you rewind the film mid-roll, the display would show "E" and the film cassette icon would blink. I expect the camera would not allow any shutter actuations without opening/closing the camera back. So I'm not sure how your camera went from ~28 to 0. Also, when film is first loaded in a F60, the frame counter shows 1. If it shows 0, I really don't know what that indicates. Is there any possibility that the LCD is faulty, and it was showing 30, but _appeared_ as 0?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a photos after a complete film rewind would not have affected your 28 previous photos since the camera would have roll the entire film back into its light-tight cassette / holder. I'm however pretty sure your camera would let you know in some way you have no active film to take pictures!

Taking a photos after a partial film rewind would  end double exposing photos

But the key question here is "Has the camera really rewound the film": a camera rarely rewinds a film on it own...

Is your conclusion of the camera rewinding only based on a "0" showing up on the screen or do you know of anything else that accredits the rewind theory?